# Python Replacing Words from Definitions in Text File

Tags: python, file

I've got an old informix database that was written for cobol.  All the fields are in code so my SQL queries look like.

```
SELECT uu00012 FROM uu0001;
```

This is pretty hard to read.

I have a text file with the field definitions like

```
uu00012 client
uu00013 date
uu00014 f_name
uu00015 l_name
```

I would like to swap out the code for the more english name.  Run a python script on it maybe and have a file with the english names saved.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just create another database and fill it up with the old values ?

Comment: Yes a lookup table solution would work for this as well...lots of possibilities :)

Answer (score 1):

If each piece is definitely a separate word, `re.sub` is definitely the way to go here:

```
#create a mapping of old vars to new vars.
with open('definitions') as f:
    d = dict( [x.split() for x in f] )

def my_replace(match):
    #if the match is in the dictionary, replace it, otherwise, return the match unchanged.
    return d.get( match.group(), match.group() )

with open('inquiry') as f:
    for line in f:
        print re.sub( r'\w+', my_replace, line )
```

Comment: Efficiency is usually not a factor in things like these. Readability is though, and I find it severely lacking :(

Comment: I think this is still far too complicated.  Python emphasizes simple easy to read code that leverages built in types and thier methods.  This can be a simple dict or list population

Comment: @nightcracker -- do the comments help?

Comment: @Justin.Wood -- This is a complicated problem.  what happens if the mapping is `foo replace bar, foocat replace barcat`.  The order you do these replacements matters and that is the part which makes this answer complicated.  Of course, the `re` solution I provided is much simpler (and probably better), but since I don't know enough about the variable names to construct a suitable re, I'm leaving the first method.

Comment: @mgilson: a bit, but it is overly complex in places, and doesn't follow PEP8. I would ditch the sorting (respect the order in which the translations were provided), for one.

Comment: @nightcracker -- dicts are unordered.  Using a dict, **there is no way to respect the order in which the translations are provided**,  I can add whitespace to make it respect PEP 8 if that's the problem ... Are there other issues with PEP 8 other than whitespace I should address?

Comment: @mgilson: I know dicts are unordered. The conclusion would be, indeed, to not use a `dict`.

Comment: @mgilson - Maybe I am missing something, but I don't see why the replacements need to be complicated.  The mapping format has been provided as a simple line terminated space divided set of pairs.  The later replacement format isnt specified, but surely can be searched on by exact match only in the string.  What am I missing that this needs to be sorted at all?  if its mapped to a dict (which granted I didnt do in my post, but would be easy to change) the key isnt going to match on a substring of it

Comment: @Justin.Wood What happens if you have a string like `"The dog ran into the doghouse"` and you want to replace `"dog"` with `"ferret"` and `"doghouse"` with `"cage"`?  You need to guarantee that you will replace doghouse before you replace dog.  Otherwise you might get `"the ferret ran into the ferrethouse"`.  Even my more complicated solution isn't good enough if the values in the dict might have the same strings that make up the keys.  (which is why `re` really is the way to go here)

Comment: but we are replace unique strings like 'uu000018' with english words... if the dict looks like `{'u0007':'dog','u00071':'doghouse'}`, pulling the value will always retrieve the EXACT key/value from the dict.  it doesnt return substring matched keys....

Comment: @Justin.Wood -- Yes, given the strings that are mentioned above, you're right.  sorting is probably unnecessary, but I was trying to attack the problem from the most general perspective I could think of it and it's a somewhat complicated problem.  Anyway, based on the pushback I'm getting, I'll probably delete the first part of this answer because the second part is better anyway (and nobody seems to have a problem with it).

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually,

I would probably first build a mapping of codings -> english (in memory or o.

Then, for each coding in your map, scan your file and replace with the codes mapped english equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
infile = open('filename.txt','r')
namelist = []
for each in infile.readlines():
    namelist.append((each.split(' ')[0],each.split(' ')[1]))
```

this will give you a list of key,value pairs

i dont know what you want to do with the results from there though, you need to be more explicit

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = '''uu00012 client
uu00013 date
uu00014 f_name
uu00015 l_name'''

dictionary = dict(map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), [x.split() for x in dictionary.split('\n')]))

def process_sql(sql, d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        sql = sql.replace(k, v)
    return sql

sql = process_sql('SELECT f_name FROM client;', dictionary)
```

build `dictionary`:

```
{'date': 'uu00013', 'l_name': 'uu00015', 'f_name': 'uu00014', 'client': 'uu00012'}
```

then run thru your SQL and replace human readable values with coded stuff. The result is:

```
SELECT uu00014 FROM uu00012;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

f = open("dictfile.txt")

d = {}
for mapping in f.readlines():
    l, r = mapping.split(" ")
    d[re.compile(l)] = r.strip("\n")

sql = open("orig.sql")
out = file("translated.sql", "w")

for line in sql.readlines():
    for r in d.keys():
        line = r.sub(d[r], line)
    out.write(line)
```